# Is there any way to make Google Chrome use current Windows theme, not its own?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, themes

I was setting up my girlfriend's laptop for her and I thought I would use a cool Windows 7 theme I found on DeviantArt.

I got a nice clean looking transparent theme.  The problems is: Google Chrome stands out a ton!

Is there any way I can make Chrome follow the other Windows theme?

Comment: Related : http://superuser.com/questions/376868/how-to-disable-chrome-themes-skins-and-get-default-window-decorations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is remove the `theme_frame` line from the Chrome theme's manifest file.

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FnrsRbzDlNU) is a brief YouTube tutorial on how to do that.

However, once you have followed the steps in that page you need to reload the theme, this is what confused me earlier.  To reload the theme (in Chrome) go to *Settings » Extensions » Load unpacked theme.*

That will open a dialogue box.  In that box select the folder that the manifest file is directly inside of.

Now your Chrome theme should match your Windows theme!

Comment: It doesn't work for me, just reverts it to the default not-the-Windows-standard-settings look.

Answer (score 1):

Right click in the top left corner next to your tabs. Click *Use system title bar and borders*.

Or use Chromium.

Comment: What does Chromium do differently?

Answer (score 0):

Use the chrome theme "White Minimalism (transparent)" from the chrome store.  It'll use window frame of windows theme even the uxtheme patched style themes.

Comment: This theme does not appear to do what you say. It uses transparency a la Aero, but it does not actually use the Windows UX theming.