# How to let software not override the currently defined windows-theme?

Tags: windows, themes

Here I read the topic on how to force Google Chrome using the defined windows-theme for its interface instead of imposing the own Google-Chrome-interface. URL: [How to disable Chrome themes/skins and get default window decorations?](https://superuser.com/questions/376868/how-to-disable-chrome-themes-skins-and-get-default-window-decorations)

I am rather annoyed by the increasing number of programs that override my set windows-theme (i.e. 'classic' W98-style with custom colour scheme)! 
Also new versions of programs I use do come up with their own interface imposed upon, let's say, my visual choice. Mostly they come with a Vista or W8 lookalike.

Quote from above mentioned topic:

> Every other program in existence (with the exception of Microsoft
>   Office) can manage to follow the default window decoration style
>   defined in the OS (...)

I wonder how one achieve this? Some registry-tweak? I tried to disable 'Visual themes' via properties, tab compatibility in Win7, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't bother to quote [the comment](https://superuser.com/questions/376868/how-to-disable-chrome-themes-skins-and-get-default-window-decorations#comment687678_563425) completely, and seem to have conveniently left out the important portion at the end:

> ... its what the OS does for you fully automatically ***unless the programmer actively goes out of his way to make his program disrespect the user's preferences***.

With some (very few) apps that simply apply external images as skins/themes, if you delete the image resources the apps *might* not complain and fall back to the default Windows look.

However if the programmer overrides the default UI controls provided by the OS and chooses to use his own custom creations, there's no way you can force the app to behave otherwise short of hacking it in some way, and I'm pretty sure *that's* not going to be possible 99.99% of the time.

An alternate solution might be to use something like [WindowBlinds](http://www.stardock.com/products/windowblinds/) along with a Windows "Classic" skin (you'll have to see if one exists or create it yourself). Although this sounds redundant, it should help you skin those apps so that they look like they're using the default Win98-style theme you prefer.